# Generate SQL statements from a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I am loading data from various sources (csv, xls, json etc...) into Pandas dataframes and I would like to generate statements to create and fill a SQL database with this data. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

I know pandas has a `to_sql` function, but that only works on a database connection, it can not generate a string.

### Example

What I would like is to take a dataframe like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dates = pd.date_range('20130101',periods=6)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4),index=dates,columns=list('ABCD'))
```

And a function that would generate this (this example is PostgreSQL but any would be fine):

```
CREATE TABLE data
(
  index timestamp with time zone,
  "A" double precision,
  "B" double precision,
  "C" double precision,
  "D" double precision
)
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

If you only want the 'CREATE TABLE' sql code (and not the insert of the data), you can use the `get_schema` function of the pandas.io.sql module:

```
In [10]: print pd.io.sql.get_schema(df.reset_index(), 'data')
CREATE TABLE "data" (
  "index" TIMESTAMP,
  "A" REAL,
  "B" REAL,
  "C" REAL,
  "D" REAL
)
```

Some notes:

- I had to use `reset_index` because it otherwise didn't include the index
- If you provide an sqlalchemy engine of a certain database flavor, the result will be adjusted to that flavor (eg the data type names).

Comment: Is it possible to get the insert data, in order to do an update/insert?

Comment: @joris how does one specify the sqlalchemy engine?

Comment: I see RustyShackleford has already found it, but here is how you specify the engine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51294670/3279262

Answer (score 36):

## GENERATE SQL CREATE STATEMENT FROM DATAFRAME

```
SOURCE = df
TARGET = data
```

### GENERATE SQL CREATE STATEMENT FROM DATAFRAME

```
def SQL_CREATE_STATEMENT_FROM_DATAFRAME(SOURCE, TARGET):

# SQL_CREATE_STATEMENT_FROM_DATAFRAME(SOURCE, TARGET)
# SOURCE: source dataframe
# TARGET: target table to be created in database

    import pandas as pd
    sql_text = pd.io.sql.get_schema(SOURCE.reset_index(), TARGET)   
    return sql_text
```

### Check the SQL `CREATE TABLE` Statement String

```
print('\n\n'.join(sql_text))
```

### GENERATE SQL INSERT STATEMENT FROM DATAFRAME

```
def SQL_INSERT_STATEMENT_FROM_DATAFRAME(SOURCE, TARGET):
    sql_texts = []
    for index, row in SOURCE.iterrows():       
        sql_texts.append('INSERT INTO '+TARGET+' ('+ str(', '.join(SOURCE.columns))+ ') VALUES '+ str(tuple(row.values)))        
    return sql_texts
```

### Check the SQL `INSERT INTO` Statement String

```
print('\n\n'.join(sql_texts))
```

Comment: Works just fine. What is the best way to create an update statement based on this solution?

Comment: i tried this insert statement but it seems it does not handle Nulls . Generated Insert statement had nan for NULL values and my query tried to insert nan in these fields.

Comment: Probably would be way more efficient to batch this up to the max sql query size, right?

Answer (score 11):

### Insert Statement Solution

Not sure if this is the absolute best way to do it but this is more efficient than using `df.iterrows()` as that is very slow. Also this takes care of `nan` values with the help of regular expressions.

```
import re

def get_insert_query_from_df(df, dest_table):

    insert = """
    INSERT INTO `{dest_table}` (
        """.format(dest_table=dest_table)

    columns_string = str(list(df.columns))[1:-1]
    columns_string = re.sub(r' ', '\n        ', columns_string)
    columns_string = re.sub(r'\'', '', columns_string)

    values_string = ''

    for row in df.itertuples(index=False,name=None):
        values_string += re.sub(r'nan', 'null', str(row))
        values_string += ',\n'

    return insert + columns_string + ')\n     VALUES\n' + values_string[:-2] + ';'
```

Comment: what is `re` supposed to be?

Comment: @Rainb `re` stands for "Regular Expression". You can import Python's regular expression library with the command `import re`

Comment: @eitanlees shouldn't that be included in the answer?

Comment: @Rainb I think it would be good to include that in the answer. I will edit hunterm's answer :)

Answer (score 6):

If you're just looking to generate a string with inserts based on `pandas.DataFrame` - I'd suggest using bulk sql insert syntax as suggested by @rup.

Here's an example of a [function](https://gist.github.com/absoup/1f2295c3d51487cd805d50b14fb54ea9) I wrote for that purpose:

```py
import pandas as pd
import re


def df_to_sql_bulk_insert(df: pd.DataFrame, table: str, **kwargs) -> str:
    """Converts DataFrame to bulk INSERT sql query
    >>> data = [(1, "_suffixnan", 1), (2, "Noneprefix", 0), (3, "fooNULLbar", 1, 2.34)]
    >>> df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["id", "name", "is_deleted", "balance"])
    >>> df
       id        name  is_deleted  balance
    0   1  _suffixnan           1      NaN
    1   2  Noneprefix           0      NaN
    2   3  fooNULLbar           1     2.34
    >>> query = df_to_sql_bulk_insert(df, "users", status="APPROVED", address=None)
    >>> print(query)
    INSERT INTO users (id, name, is_deleted, balance, status, address)
    VALUES (1, '_suffixnan', 1, NULL, 'APPROVED', NULL),
           (2, 'Noneprefix', 0, NULL, 'APPROVED', NULL),
           (3, 'fooNULLbar', 1, 2.34, 'APPROVED', NULL);
    """
    df = df.copy().assign(**kwargs)
    columns = ", ".join(df.columns)
    tuples = map(str, df.itertuples(index=False, name=None))
    values = re.sub(r"(?<=\W)(nan|None)(?=\W)", "NULL", (",\n" + " " * 7).join(tuples))
    return f"INSERT INTO {table} ({columns})\nVALUES {values};"
```

By the way, it converts `nan`/`None` entries to `NULL` and it's possible to pass constant column=value pairs as keyword arguments (see `status="APPROVED"` and `address=None` arguments in docstring example).

Generally, it works faster since any database does a lot of work for a single insert: checking the constraints, building indices, flushing, writing to log, etc. This complex operations can be optimized by the database when doing several-in-one operation, and not calling the engine one-by-one.

Comment: The regex seems really slow for large queries.

Comment: Not sure if spaces count towards max SQL statement length, but seems like adding the 7 blank spaces is not needed if we're not going to be looking at the query.

Answer (score 4):

**SINGLE INSERT QUERY SOLUTION**

I didn't find the above answers to suit my needs. I wanted to create **one** single insert statement for a dataframe with each row as the values. This can be achieved by the below:

```
import re 
import pandas as pd 

table = 'your_table_name_here'

# You can read from CSV file here... just using read_sql_query as an example

df = pd.read_sql_query(f'select * from {table}', con=db_connection)


cols = ', '.join(df.columns.to_list()) 
vals = []

for index, r in df.iterrows():
    row = []
    for x in r:
        row.append(f"'{str(x)}'")

    row_str = ', '.join(row)
    vals.append(row_str)

f_values = [] 
for v in vals:
    f_values.append(f'({v})')

# Handle inputting NULL values
f_values = ', '.join(f_values) 
f_values = re.sub(r"('None')", "NULL", f_values)

sql = f"insert into {table} ({cols}) values {f_values};" 

print(sql)

db.dispose()
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to write the file by yourself, you may also retrieve columns names and dtypes and build a dictionary to convert pandas data types to sql data types.

As an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dates = pd.date_range('20130101',periods=6)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4),index=dates,columns=list('ABCD'))

tableName = 'table'
columnNames = df.columns.values.tolist()
columnTypes =  map(lambda x: x.name, df.dtypes.values)

# Storing column names and dtypes in a dataframe

tableDef = pd.DataFrame(index = range(len(df.columns) + 1), columns=['cols', 'dtypes'])

tableDef.iloc[0]           = ['index', df.index.dtype.name]
tableDef.loc[1:, 'cols']   = columnNames
tableDef.loc[1:, 'dtypes'] = columnTypes

# Defining a dictionnary to convert dtypes

conversion = {'datetime64[ns]':'timestamp with time zone', 'float64':'double precision'}

# Writing sql in a file

f = open('yourdir\%s.sql' % tableName, 'w')

f.write('CREATE TABLE %s\n' % tableName)
f.write('(\n')

for i, row in tableDef.iterrows():
    sep = ",\n" if i < tableDef.index[-1] else "\n"
    f.write('\t\"%s\" %s%s' % (row['cols'], conversion[row['dtypes']], sep))

f.write(')')

f.close()
```

You can do the same way to populate your table with INSERT INTO.

Comment: I used your code and got error looks like as "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxx.py", line 58, in <module>
    f.write('\t\"%s\" %s%s' % (row['cols'], conversion[row['dtypes']], sep))
KeyError: <map object at 0x000002540ACBA5C0>". Then i wrapped the `map()` inside the `list()` and this works like a charm. Thank you for your script.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I used was to send the *dataframe* to a DB *in memory*, using SQLite3.

After that I dump the DB, writing the statements in a *.sql* file.

... just for demo I created an example file:

```
from datetime import datetime

import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


# Load Dataset
dataset_name = 'iris'
df = sns.load_dataset(dataset_name)

# Add Name to Index
df.index.name = 'Id'

# Results
df.head()
```

We create an *engine* using [SQL Alchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/). This connection will be used by *pandas*, to send the data to the temporary memory, and also by ***SQLite3***, to *dump* the contents of the *database*.

```
# Create Engine with SQL Alchemy (used by pandas)
engine = create_engine(f'sqlite://', echo=False)

# Send data to temporary SQLite3
df.to_sql(name=dataset_name, index=True, con=engine, if_exists='replace')
```

Finally, we indicate the path to the output file and do the *iterdump*.

```
# Output file
output_file = f'sql - {dataset_name}.sql'

# Para cada
with open(output_file, 'w') as f:
    # Date
    data_agora = datetime.today().strftime('%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S')
    
    f.write(
        '/****** Query para criação e inserção de registros no DB ******/\n'
    )
    f.write('/*\n')
    f.write(f'São {len(df)} registros\n')
    f.write(f'Obtidos na tabela "{dataset_name}"\n')
    f.write('\n')
    f.write(f'Query feita por Michel Metran em {(data_agora)},\n')
    f.write('*/\n')
    f.write('\r\n')    
    
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        for line in conn.connection.iterdump():            
            f.write(f'{line}\n')
            print(line)
    
    # Close Connection
    conn.close()
```

To make life easier, I created a function inside a package that I maintain, called "traquitanas", with the function, being necessary to install the package and use the function:

```
#!pip3 install traquitanas --upgrade
from traquitanas.data import convert_to_sql

convert_to_sql.convert_dataframe_to_sql(df, output_file, dataset_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking the user @Jaris's post to get the CREATE, I extended it further to work for any CSV

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

db = './database.db'
csv = './data.csv'
table_name = 'data'

# create db and setup schema
df = pd.read_csv(csv)
create_table_sql = pd.io.sql.get_schema(df.reset_index(), table_name)
conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute(create_table_sql)
conn.commit()


# now we can insert data
def insert_data(row, c):
    values = str(row.name)+','+','.join([str('"'+str(v)+'"') for v in row])
    sql_insert=f"INSERT INTO {table_name} VALUES ({values})"

    try:
        c.execute(sql_insert)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"SQL:{sql_insert} \n failed with Error:{e}")



# use apply to loop over dataframe and call insert_data on each row
df.apply(lambda row: insert_data(row, c), axis=1)

# finally commit all those inserts into the database
conn.commit()
```

Hopefully this is more simple than the alternative answers and more pythonic!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on if you can forego generating an intermediate representation of the SQL statement; You can just outright execute the insert statement as well.

```
con.executemany("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO data (A, B, C, D) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", list(df_.values))
```

This worked a little better as there is less messing around with string generation.