# How to specify flavor of sql in pd.io.sql.get_schema?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, schema

I am trying to use `pd.io.sql.get_schema` to generate a postgres schema from a dataframe.

There is no documentation for `pd.io.sql.get_schema` but from this(https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9960) link it says that I can specify a flavor of sql.

However this feature seems to be deprecated instead I can specify a engine like postgresql ([Generate SQL statements from a Pandas Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31071952/generate-sql-statements-from-a-pandas-dataframe)). How do I do this?

Here is my code so far:

```
pd.io.sql.get_schema(df.reset_index(), 'data')
```

Open to all suggestions for generating schema.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe you create a connection to a postgreSQL database using SQLAlchemy and then pass that connection to the `con` kwarg. For example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy

dates = pd.date_range('20130101',periods=6)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4),index=dates,columns=list('ABCD'))

url = 'postgresql://USER:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/DATABASE'
con = sqlalchemy.create_engine(url, client_encoding='utf8')
print(pd.io.sql.get_schema(df.reset_index(), 'data', con=con))
CREATE TABLE data (
        index TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
        "A" FLOAT(53),
        "B" FLOAT(53),
        "C" FLOAT(53),
        "D" FLOAT(53)
)
```