# Easiest way to automatically add new columns to MySQL database before calling pandas df.to_sql?

Tags: python, sql, mysql, pandas, dataframe

I'm encountering an issue where I'm appending a dataframe to a table in my mysql database, but the number of columns in the dataset can be greater than or equal to the number of column currently in the database.

For example, the dataset and the table may both have 10 columns. The next time we want to export the data, the dataset might have 11+ columns. If I try to just run `df.to_sql(...)` it will give me a field error because a column(s) is not present in the table already.

What would the best approach be to first add the column to the table before exporting the dataframe in pandas? I thought about `set(columns in df) - set(columns in table)` and then manually running `ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN...` but I don't know how to dynamically map mysql datatypes to numpy datatypes

What's the best approach for this?

Comment: I find this an odd requirement.  If you can't tell what the new columns are, then this will always have to be a manual operation, right?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that I have the pandas/numpy data type of the column, but don't know what the correct mapping would be for MySQL. If I have an int64 dtype in pandas, should it be SMALLINT, INT, BIGINT, etc? I don't know the theoretical min/max of the column, only the dtype. It's difficult for this exact reason

Comment: What do you want to do with the data already in the MySQL table? Replace it? Or, if you want to keep it, what should go in the new column(s)? Will you ever change a column's data type? Or even drop a column completely? Also, what is the context of all of this? SQL is "structured" and adding columns on a regular basis feels like a SQL Anti-Pattern.

Comment: This may be a good starting point ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31071952/generate-sql-statements-from-a-pandas-dataframe (use it to get the new dataframe's schema, or even just the new columns, and parse it to generate an alter table statement).

Comment: @MatBailie this looks very promising. The context is, at a high level, I am moving data from a third-party API into my own database. The API produces different columns depending on the parameters given to it, and generally, more fields are added as they develop the API over time

Comment: From a software engineering standpoint, this is not good practice, in part for the exact reason you state.  You should not be expanding your database automatically based on the requests that come in.  That's a great Denial of Service attack vector.  Instead, the database should be expanded BEFORE you start offer to service the new API.

Answer (score 0):

After comparing the schemas, For each new column, you'll need to add it to your MySQL table. The tricky part is determining the correct MySQL data type.

```
def pandas_type_to_mysql(pandas_type):
    if pandas_type in ['int64', 'int32']:
        return 'INT'
    elif pandas_type in ['float64', 'float32']:
        return 'FLOAT'
    elif pandas_type == 'object':
        return 'TEXT'
    elif 'datetime' in pandas_type:
        return 'DATETIME'
    # Add more mappings as necessary
    return 'TEXT'  # default type

# Example usage
for col in new_columns:
    col_type = pandas_type_to_mysql(str(df[col].dtype))
    alter_statement = f"ALTER TABLE your_table_name ADD COLUMN {col} {col_type};"
    # Execute this SQL statement on your MySQL database
```

Finally, you can append your DataFrame to the MySQL table:

```
df.to_sql('your_table_name', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```